# click event on custom layout (extends LinearLayout) is not triggered in IceCream Sandwich but works on gingerbread

Tags: android, android-layout, android-event

We have a custom layout extending linearlayout, which has a button. The button has a OnClickListener set. This Layout is added to a custom view extending ScrollView(called the grid).

The onclick event on the button is recognized in gingerbread but fails in ICS. 
While debugging the code never enter the OnClick of the button, the only way i can recognize an event is 'OnTouch'

Has anybody else experienced the same with ICS?

Answer (score 1):

Ok here was the issue, with gingerbread the click event in the child view got priority over the parent's touch event , but with ICS the touch event gets the priority. In my case the   the child view had a click event and no touch event , but its parent had code for touch. Once i commented out the code for touch event in the parent view, the code stepped into the click event of the child view